# How to migrate an existing Btrfs subvolume to *systemd-homed*

Tags: systemd, btrfs, home

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears to me that *Linux* is migrating to *systemd-homed* to manage home directories.

My home directory is on a *Btrfs* subvolume. I see that [homectl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/homectl.html) mentions that *Btrfs* subvolumes are supported. Is there any method to migrate an existing *Btrfs* subvolume to *systemd-homed*?

On [Converting Existing Users to systemd-homed](https://systemd.io/CONVERTING_TO_HOMED/) I only see a method to copy paste the entire home directory. This isn't quite ideal, since:

- My home directory is fairy large.
- I use *Btrfs* snapshots for backups. A copy might ruin my incremental backup, which will grow my backup disk by an unreasaonble size.

So I'm wondering if there's a more direct way to migrate, without copying any files.

Comment: You probably meant to say that some distributions are moving to "homed" (version 246 july 2020), in particular RedHat. There is no great need to change to this unless you want to take advantage of what it offers, like moving your disk between different hosts, or you wish to contribute to its development. Consider waiting at least a year until it is mature and, for example, becomes the default mechanism provided when installing a new system for your preferred distribution.

Comment: just disable it and ignore it, like you should do with all the other worthless, poorly-implemented crap that the systemd devs shoe-horn into what would otherwise be a fairly decent init system.